# Understanding the order when reshaping a tensor

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, reshape, tensor

For a tensor:

```py
x = torch.tensor([
    [
        [[0.4495, 0.2356],
          [0.4069, 0.2361],
          [0.4224, 0.2362]],
                   
         [[0.4357, 0.6762],
          [0.4370, 0.6779],
          [0.4406, 0.6663]]
    ],    
    [
        [[0.5796, 0.4047],
          [0.5655, 0.4080],
          [0.5431, 0.4035]],
         
         [[0.5338, 0.6255],
          [0.5335, 0.6266],
          [0.5204, 0.6396]]
    ]
])
```

Firstly would like to split it into 2 (x.shape[0]) tensors then concat them. Here, i dont really have to actually split it as long as i get the correct output, but it makes a lot more sense to me visually to split it then concat them back together.

For example:

```py
# the shape of the splits are always the same
split1 = torch.tensor([
    [[0.4495, 0.2356],
    [0.4069, 0.2361],
    [0.4224, 0.2362]],

    [[0.4357, 0.6762],
    [0.4370, 0.6779],
    [0.4406, 0.6663]]
])
split2 = torch.tensor([
    [[0.5796, 0.4047],
    [0.5655, 0.4080],
    [0.5431, 0.4035]],

    [[0.5338, 0.6255],
    [0.5335, 0.6266],
    [0.5204, 0.6396]]
])

split1 = torch.cat((split1[0], split1[1]), dim=1)
split2 = torch.cat((split2[0], split2[1]), dim=1)
what_i_want = torch.cat((split1, split2), dim=0).reshape(x.shape[0], split1.shape[0], split1.shape[1])
```

[image]

For the above result, i thought directly reshaping x.reshape([2, 3, 4]) would work, it resulted in the correct dimension but incorrect result.

In general i am:

1. not sure how to split the tensor into x.shape[0] tensors.
2. confused about how reshape works. Most of the time i am able to get the dimension right, but the order of the numbers are always incorrect.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like `x` is (2,2,3,2) shape.  `reshape` can combine adjacent dimensions, e.g. (4,3,2), (2,2,6), since it does not reorder underlying flattened data.  The data order that you desired probably requires an axis transpose/swap.  Since their several possible swaps I won't try to suggest the right one.

Answer (score 6):

The order of the elements in memory in python, pytorch, numpy, c++ etc. are in [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) ordering:

```
[ first, second
  third, forth  ]
```

While in matlab, fortran, etc. the order is [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order):

```
[ first,  third
  second, fourth ]
```

For higher dimensional tensors, this means elements are ordered from the last dimension to the first.

You can easily visualize it using [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html#torch.arange) followed by [`.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view):

```py
a = torch.arange(24)
a.view(2,3,4)
```

Results with

> ```
> tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
>     [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
>     [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],
>
>    [[12, 13, 14, 15],
>     [16, 17, 18, 19],
>     [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
> ```

As you can see the elements are ordered first by row (last dimension), then by column, and finally by the first dimension.

When you `reshape` a tensor, you do not change the underlying order of the elements, only the `shape` of the tensor. However, if you [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) a tensor - you change the underlying order of the elements.

Look at the difference between `a.view(3,2,4)` and `a.permute(0,1,2)` - the `shape` of the resulting two tensors is the same, but not the ordering of elements:

```py
In []: a.view(3,2,4)
Out[]:
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

        [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15]],

        [[16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

In []: a.permute(1,0,2)
Out[]:
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [12, 13, 14, 15]],

        [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [16, 17, 18, 19]],

        [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example, using `numpy` methods (I don't have tensorflow installed):

```
In [559]: x = np.array([
     ...:     [
     ...:         [[0.4495, 0.2356],
     ...:           [0.4069, 0.2361],
     ...:           [0.4224, 0.2362]],
     ...: 
     ...:          [[0.4357, 0.6762],
     ...:           [0.4370, 0.6779],
     ...:           [0.4406, 0.6663]]
     ...:     ],
     ...:     [
     ...:         [[0.5796, 0.4047],
     ...:           [0.5655, 0.4080],
     ...:           [0.5431, 0.4035]],
     ...: 
     ...:          [[0.5338, 0.6255],
     ...:           [0.5335, 0.6266],
     ...:           [0.5204, 0.6396]]
     ...:     ]
     ...: ])
In [560]: x.shape
Out[560]: (2, 2, 3, 2)

In [562]: s1=np.concatenate((x[0,0],x[0,1]), axis=1)
In [563]: s2=np.concatenate((x[1,0],x[1,1]), axis=1)
In [564]: s1.shape
Out[564]: (3, 4)

In [565]: new =np.concatenate((s1,s2), axis=0)
In [566]: new.shape
Out[566]: (6, 4)
In [567]: new.reshape(2,3,4)
Out[567]: 
array([[[0.4495, 0.2356, 0.4357, 0.6762],
        [0.4069, 0.2361, 0.437 , 0.6779],
        [0.4224, 0.2362, 0.4406, 0.6663]],

       [[0.5796, 0.4047, 0.5338, 0.6255],
        [0.5655, 0.408 , 0.5335, 0.6266],
        [0.5431, 0.4035, 0.5204, 0.6396]]])
```

`numpy` has a `stack` that joins arrays on a new axis, so we can skip the last concatenate and reshape with

```
np.stack((s1,s2))    # or
np.array((s1,s2))
```

The direct way to get there is to swap the middle 2 dimensions:

```
In [569]: x.transpose(0,2,1,3).shape
Out[569]: (2, 3, 2, 2)

In [571]: x.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2,3,4)
Out[571]: 
array([[[0.4495, 0.2356, 0.4357, 0.6762],
        [0.4069, 0.2361, 0.437 , 0.6779],
        [0.4224, 0.2362, 0.4406, 0.6663]],

       [[0.5796, 0.4047, 0.5338, 0.6255],
        [0.5655, 0.408 , 0.5335, 0.6266],
        [0.5431, 0.4035, 0.5204, 0.6396]]])
```

`reshape` can be used to combine 'adjacent' dimensions, but doesn't reorder the underlying data.  That is `x.ravel()` remains the same with `reshape`.  While reshape of (2,2,3,2) to (2,3,4) is allowed, the apparent order of values probably is not what you want.  That might be easier to see if you try to reshape

```
In [572]: np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
Out[572]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [573]: _.reshape(3,2)
Out[573]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

compare that with a transpose:

```
In [574]: np.arange(6).reshape(2,3).transpose(1,0)
Out[574]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

The transpose/swap that I did in [569] may be hard to understand.  There are enough different ways of reordering dimensions, that it's hard to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have a tensor `x` of shape (B, C, H, W) and you want to convert it into (B, H, C * W). To achieve this, you need to do the two following steps

1. Rearrange `x` 's dimension to (B, H, C, W) to have a new tensor named `y`
2. Reshape `y` into (B, H, C * W) to have the final result

The reason for reshaping `x` into (B, H, C, W) and especially not (B, H, W, C) is that

- You want one row in the result made of the concatenation of rows of submatrices of `x` (i.e. the 3x2 matrices you indicate by `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) having the same row index.
- Pytorch 's `reshape` function operates in a row-major fashion.

Therefore, the rows need to be put on top of each other for reshape to return the desired order.

With the above reasoning, the code for getting `what_i_want` is

```
what_i_want = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(2, 3, 4)
```